# PHP ,convert string to array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

such as :

```
DEFGHIJKLMN
```

into array like:

```
$diskVolume = array('D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N');
```

Because `explode()` doesn't work for this kind of string.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You should check out the "See Also" suggestions in the php manual ("str_split() - Convert a string to an array").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split a string into its individual characters:

```
$diskVolume = str_split($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use array access to read from strings:

```
>> $a = 'CDEFGHIJKLMO';
'CDEFGHIJKLMO'
>> echo $a[2];
E
```

However you can't use it as an argument for `foreach()` and similar constructs/functions

Comment: Yup, because strings are not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Should use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
or

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($diskVolume);$i++){
echo $diskVolume[$i];
}
```